# I can't understand what is going on with a logical expression as it returns an integer

Tags: c#, logical-operators

A logical expression is returning an integer...

I've found a bug in an application and the problem was that a portion of code was completely wrong, but it was not perceived for some time because a logical expression was returning, apparently, random integers for each given integer in the expression.
I could fix the logical condition but couldn't neither understand nor explain to the customer what was going on with the previous code.

```cs
// This is the actual code
for (int i = 1; i <= (queryResult.ItemCount & 4020); i++) {...}
```

```cs
// My simulation in the Visual Studio C# interactive console
int qr = 0;

Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 1;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 10;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 1000;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 2000;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 4000;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 4020;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 5000;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
qr = 10000;
Print(qr + " - " + (qr & 4020));
```

I would expect
"4020 - True"
once and many
" - False"

but actually I've got:
"0 - 0"
"1 - 0"
"10 - 0"
"1000 - 928"
"2000 - 1936"
"4000 - 4000"
"4020 - 4020"
"5000 - 896"
"10000 - 1808"

Could anybody explain me what's going on here? What kind of expression/operators/types I'm not interpreting right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: What do you think `queryResult.ItemCount & 4020` does?

Comment: I'm confused - why do you expect `True` or `False` to ever be printed? The code uses a bitwise logical AND with two integers, so it would return an integer. There are no Boolean expressions in the code.

Comment: @RufusL, I didn't know that `&` would have the bitwise behavior when the operands are integers. I always used with booleans and behave as I expected, as a logical AND.

Comment: I still don't see why `qr & 4020` would evaluate to `true`. Perhaps you were thinking of an equality operator, like `qr == 4020`?

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the [bitwise logical AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-) when there operands are number types/integrals, and returns an integral value. The bitwise operator is for doing binary maths.

When the operands are both `boolean`, then `&` becomes a [Boolean logical AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-), returning a boolean value.

As `query.ItemCount` is an `int`, and `4020` is an `int`, `queryResult.ItemCount & 4020` the operator will be always a bitwise logical AND operator, and the values you've listed are all the [correct result for this operator](https://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/?data_type=10&number1=1000&number2=4020&operator=AND).

Now as to why the original developer of the application has chosen to use the bitwise and operator as part of the exit condition of the loop, completely depends on the application's requirements. But the values returned are not random.

Comment: Great! That answered my question. I could achieve the behavior expected for the application requirements by changing into `for (int i = 1; i <= qr.DocCount & i <= 4020; i++) `. Thanks everybody for clarifying.

Comment: @RoanMarques, I would probably advise switching `i <= qr.DocCount & i <= 4020` to `i <= qr.DocCount && i <= 4020` as it removes all ambiguity and clarifies that you want to do a boolean logical and operation. Infact, always use `&&` for boolean logic.